# How to change the background image using img file from database in Web2py

Tags: web2py

What I am trying to do is to keep changing the background image using image files that are uploaded in the database instead in the `'static', 'images'` folder.

I obviously can't do this in the `css`, actually, I am not sure if this is even possible. Can I make this work in the `layout.html` or in the `View` somehow?

This is how I would display an image in the `View` if it wasn't intended to be a background-image:

```
<img src="{{=URL('download', args=pic_row.pics)}}"/>
```

Of course, this approach to display a background-mage won't work:

```
<section id="main" class="main row" style="background-image:{{=URL('download', args=pic_row.pics)}}">
```

..but is there a way I can actually achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<section id="main" class="main row" style="background-image:{{=URL('download', args=pic_row.pics)}}">
```

The above method proposed in the question is close, but the CSS syntax is incorrect. The `style` attribute should be:

```
"background-image: url('{{=URL('download', args=pic_row.pics)}}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Anthony´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334360/web2py-how-should-i-display-an-uploaded-image-that-is-stored-in-a-database).

With this it should be possible if you include

```
<style>
    body {
        background: url('{{=URL('download',args=picture_name)}}')
    }
</style>
```

into your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it seceral different ways but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: This is close, but the URL must be surrounded by quotes: `url('{{=URL('download', args=pic_row.pics)}}')`.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it work in CSS?

I'm not sure this is the best way, but surely you can construct a controller that returns an image from the database?

**controllers/random.py**:

```
def image():
    image = db(db.images ...).select().first() # get the image from db
    from io import StringIO
    stream = StringIO(image.bytes)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
    return response.stream(stream, 1024**2)
```

And then just point your stylesheet to it.

**some_view.html**:

```
...
<style>
body { background: url("/random/image"); }
</style>
...
```

Comment: The `image` function is unnecessary, as web2py already includes a built-in facility for streaming uploaded files. Otherwise, this method should work.