# Conditional statement using request.env.http_referer Web2py

Tags: web2py

I am trying to use `request.env.http_referer` but it seems I am missing something.

This is what I tried in the `View`:

```
{{if request.env.http_referer != 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_wp/default/show_test/1':}}
<h1>Something</h1>
{{pass}}
```

This works but depending on the `args`, the URL will have a different ending. How can I make this work with any number at the and of the URL after the `show_test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{if not request.env.http_referer.startswith(
      'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_wp/default/show_test/'):}}
```

For more sophisticated pattern matching, you can of course use regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks very much. I should have thought of that.

Comment: Anthony, I wonder if you can help me with on other problem which I can't solve for a while now. This is the question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162866/how-to-change-the-background-image-using-img-file-from-database-in-web2py/30213309#30213309